# Keras Conv1d input shape problem, Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to use a conv1d to predict time series, but I have trouble with the conv1d input shape.
My data 406 samples of 10 values in temporal order.
The goal is to predict sample N+1 using sample N as input.

Here is a sample of my code :

```py
print(data_x.shape)
# (406, 10)
print(data_y.shape)
# (406, 10)


inputs = Input(10, 1)
x = Conv1D(64, 2, input_shape=(10,1))(inputs)
x = Dense(64, "relu")(x)
x = Dense(64, "relu")(x)
x = Dense(10, "sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(inputs, x)
model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(data_x, data_y,
                    batch_size=10, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

But I get this error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 10)` .

I don't know what I am missing, I even tried to do `data_x = data_x.reshape(-1,10,1)` but with the same results.

Comment: If you use code that is commented, it won't do much... In your last line lies the answer.

Comment: It was just a copy/past mistake.
I tried with `data_x = data_x.reshape(-1,10,1)`.
And with :

```python
data_x = data_x.reshape(-1,10,1)

inputs = Input(10, 1,1)

x = Conv1D(64, 2, input_shape=(10,1,1))(inputs)
```

Comment: Use exactly the code in the post, but add `data_x = data_x.reshape(-1,10,1)` before the CNN

Comment: As I told before, I tried with the exact code I put in my original post and with the addition of `data_x = data_x.reshape(-1, 10, 1)`, resulting with `data_x` having a shape of `(406, 10, 1)`.

This result in the exact same error :
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 10)
`

Comment: Right, my bad..

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0)` instead of reshape.

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = (10, 1)
x = tf.random.normal(inputs)
inp = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 2, input_shape=(10,1))(inp)
```

**Output**

```
(1, 9, 64)
```